# Update the list defined in a top-level CMakeLists.txt in a .cmake function called from sub directory CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

I am trying to use a .cmake file to update a global list to collect all the library names and use that list to link all the libraries from the top-level CMakeLists.txt file but unfortunately at the end I see the list is empty. Please see the CMakeLists.txt and .cmake calls in below:

```
ROOOT
|
---> CMakeLists.txt
     This file creates an empty list
     set(global_list "")
|
---> sub_dir1
        |
        ---> CMakeLists.txt
             This file includes a build.cmake file
        ---> build.cmake
             This file defines a cmake function to update the global_list
             function(update_list)
                list(APPEND global_list ${lib_name})
                set(global_list ${global_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
             endfunction()
---> sub_dir2
        |
        ---> CMakeLists.txt
             This file calls update_list function to send the lib name as an input
             update_list(lib_sub_dir2)
---> sub_dir3
        |
        ---> CMakeLists.txt
             This file calls update_list function to send the lib name as an input
             update_list(lib_sub_dir3)
---> sub_dir4
        |
        ---> CMakeLists.txt
             This file calls update_list function to send the lib name as an input
             update_list(lib_sub_dir4)
```

At the end when the root level CMakeLists.txt file prints the global_list it shows empty.

Requirement: global_list should contain lib_sub_dir2, lib_sub_dir3, lib_sub_dir4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the scope of variables. Every subdirectory added via `add_subdirectory` and every call of a cmake `function()` introduces a new variable scope. Variables of ancestor scopes are readable, but if you write a variable, you're working with a variable in the current scope. The only way of communicating the information to the parent scope is to use [`set(VAR_NAME value PARENT_SCOPE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html).

Using this command isn't well maintainable when using `add_subdirectory` though, since you need to remember to use `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)` in every subdirectory.

You could simply introduce a global cmake property of your own for this though.

```
#introduce the property
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_LIST)

# add "new_element"
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GLOBAL_LIST new_element)

# store the current value of the GLOBAL_LIST in the GLOBAL_LIST_VALUE variable
get_property(GLOBAL_LIST_VALUE GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_LIST)
```

Introduce the global property in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` and you'll be able to add to the property and read the current value of the property from anywhere using the commands above.